# React is not running

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-barcode@1.4.1
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.4" from @ant-design/charts@1.4.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ant-design/charts
npm ERR!     @ant-design/charts@"^1.4.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   65 more (@ant-design/flowchart, @ant-design/graphs, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from react-barcode@1.4.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-barcode
npm ERR!   react-barcode@"^1.4.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from react-barcode@1.4.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-barcode
npm ERR!     react-barcode@"^1.4.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\ghost\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-01-24T07_50_41_550Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ghost\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-01-24T07_50_41_550Z-debug-0.log

I tried `npm install` and this error is showing.
I also used `npm start` But it also showed error

`npm WARN config global` --global`,` --local`are deprecated. Use`--location=global` instead.

> frontend@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: npm install --force

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the version of **react-scripts** did not match your project.

Run `npm install react-scripts --save`

Your project should be running fine